# How does my MVC5 controller find a View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I was checking through the code on our project, and found an Action method in our code without a view. `CustomForms.Index` didn't have a matching View, but when I run the code, up comes the view listing the appropriate records.

I'm happy that we don't get an error. But I'm curious how to figure out what View it is using.

Answer (score 0):

By convention, Razor searches for views in the following paths, in order:

```
~/Areas/{AreaName}/Views/{ControllerName}/{ActionName}.cshtml
~/Areas/{AreaName}/Views/Shared/{ActionName}.cshtml
~/Views/{ControllerName}/{ActionName}.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/{ActionName}.cshtml
```

Obviously, if you're not utilizing areas, the first two don't apply. Additionally, the view can be explicitly given, by passing a string to the `return View` call:

```
return View("Foo");
```

Would look for a view name `Foo.cshtml` in all of the above locations, instead of the action name.